# wolfmqtt library issue in stm32cube ide

Tags: stm32, wolfssl

I am added `wolfmqtt` through software packs and configure it in project.

And I am copying mqttsimple.

`mqttsimpl.h` file in my `CORE -> Inc, CORE -> Src`.

if I calling a `mqttsimple_test` function in `main.c` which is define in `mqttsimple.c`.

Showing following error:

```
ompilation terminated.
make: *** [Core/mqttsimple/subdir.mk:19: Core/mqttsimple/mqttsimple.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
../Core/Src/mqttsimple.c:38:10: fatal error: netinet/in.h: No such file or directory
   38 | #include <netinet/in.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Core/Src/subdir.mk:37: Core/Src/mqttsimple.o] Error 1
"make -j4 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

I am excluding the `mqttsimple` folder In `middleware ->third party-> wolfmqtt-> example-> mqttsimple`.

And copy the `mqttsimple.c` in `core -> src and mqttsimple.h` in `core->Inc`.

I talk to `wolfssl` team they told me to add (`#define HAVE SOCKET`) in these header file (`wolfSSL.I-CUBE-wolfMQTT_conf.h`).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a wolfMQTT library issue, this is an application issue. The example you are trying to use links against the wolfMQTT library. You are trying to call the example function `mqttsimple_test`.

You should write your MQTT client application, using the example as a guide. Call the wolfMQTT API directly.

Comment: In example they give simplemqtt folder  there is implementation of mqtt and publish and subscribe msg.
I am trying to add this in  my main.c .